# How to code and overload the function that returns itself? C++17

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, overloading, c++17

Using msvc the latest (as of 25DEC17 ).

```
    template< typename T>
    auto out_ (const T & val_) 
    {
        // do something with val_

        // error: can not deduce auto from out_
        return out_;
    }
```

The question is how to code and then write few overloads of this little 'thing' above?

Yes, it has to be msvc and C++17. No GCC 7.0.2 does not compile this either. clang have not tried yet.

Perhaps functor pattern might help?

Please advise ...

Comment: In [typed lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typed_lambda_calculus) a function returning itself is difficult (or impossible) to type. So **a function should not return itself** (and that is not specific to C++; it also fails in Ocaml, Haskell, etc...). Mathematically, a set cannot be its power set (in [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory)). IMHO, your code makes no sense.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that your lambda solution works with g++. clang++ complaints with

```
 error: variable 'out_' declared with deduced type 'auto' cannot appear in its own initializer
 return out_ ;
        ^
```

I suspect that is right clang++ refusing your code (and wrong g++ accepting it) but I'm not sure.

Anyway, I find the idea of a lambda returning itself interesting.

I propose a non-lambda (but I hope standard compliant and portable) solution based on a struct with a template `operator()` returning a reference to the object.

I mean

```
struct outS
 {
   template <typename T>
   outS const & operator() (T const & t) const
    {
      std::cout << t;

      return *this;
    }
 };
```

So you can write, by example,

```
outS{}("Hello ")("from ")("GCC ")(__VERSION__)(" !");
```

The problem with `std::endl` is a different one.

The problem is that `std::endl` is defined (see [CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)) as

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

that is, `std::endl` is a template function.

You can write

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

or

```
std::wcout << std::endl;
```

because the operator `<<` select the specific version of `std::endl`; but you can't pass it to `outS` as follows

```
outS{}(std::endl);
```

because `outS` can't select the specific version of `std::endl`.

So you have to explicit it; to match `std::endl` with `std::cout`, the template parameters for `std::endl` are `char` and `std::char_traits<char>`.

So you can write (ugly, I know)

```
outS{}(std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>);
```

But if you implement a `struct` based solution (`outS`), you can add a `endl()` method

```
outS const & endl () const
 {
   std::cout << std::endl;

   return *this;
 }
```

so you can write

```
outS{}.endl();
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

struct outS
 {
   template <typename T>
   outS const & operator() (T const & t) const
    {
      std::cout << t;

      return *this;
    }

   outS const & endl () const
    {
      std::cout << std::endl;

      return *this;
    }

 };

int main()
 {
   outS{}("Hello ")("from ")("GCC ")(__VERSION__)(" !").endl();
 }
```

Comment: Why is most of this answer is about `cout` and `endl`?

Comment: @Barry - maybe isn't correct... but this answer is an answer (also... well... mainly) to the OP answer where show the use of `out_` and write "Why GCC 7.0.2 can not take std::endl, right now I have no time deciphering".

Comment: Many thaks @max66 for the balanced involvement. Your analysis is lucid.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the templates. Answer is auto's + lambda:

```
#include <iostream>

    auto out_ = [] ( auto & val_) 
    {
        std::cout << val_;
        return out_ ;
    };

   int main()
   {
    out_("Hello ")("from ")("GCC ")(__VERSION__)(" !"); 
    // GCC can not compile this: ( std::endl );
   }
```

I am not surprised this works as lambda is implemented as functor. Why GCC 7.0.2 can not take std::endl, right now I have no time deciphering.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b85b5f89047b5828

As for std::endl "problem" and @max66 solution I do think that C++20 will have better generic/templated lambdas where "auto" will mean "auto" ...

Few years back, while being focused on my jQuery work, I might have invented this concept and I am calling it "call stream" ... It was favorably received. There are few articles about it.

But back then (before C++11) implementation was very much like @max66 solution here. C++17 makes this simple single lambda (in my answer) into an rather elegant solution, I dare to write.

I am not sure if it will be ok for me to provide links to my blog here ...

https://dbj.org/callstream-project-euler/

Comment: "Forget the templates" - not exactly... an `auto` parameter for a lambda function transform the lambda in a "generic lambda", that is a unnamed struct with a template `operator()`; in other words, `auto & val_` is syntactic sugar for `T & val_` where `T` is a template type.

Comment: @max66 many thanks for your time and efforts.  by "forget the templates" I meant forget them and just code ... but be aware they are one level bellow ...